# Is OJDBC7 Compatible with Oracle18c?

Tags: java, oracle, ojdbc, oracle18c

Currentlt, I have an *Oracle Database Server (11g)* and many differen *Java 8* Applications on client computers. These applications mostly use *ojdbc7.jar* for database query execution.

Now, we are facing an incoming migration to *Oracle 18c*. We will work on updating dependencies for these applications, to ojdbc8.jar; however I need to know whether this is a blocking point for new version integration.

Will *ojdbc7* dependency work with *Oracle 18c*, albeit, with limited functionality? Or is it ***absolutely*** necessary to update dependency BEFORE server migration?

Hope you can shed any light on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can continue to sue ojdbc7.jar from 11.2 to connect to an Oracle 18c Database. That's supported but some new functionalities in 18c won't be available. Eventually you should also upgrade the client (ojdbc8.jar).

Answer (score 1):

ojdbc8.jar: Certified with JDK9 and JDK8, all the classes to support basic functionality for the Thin driver. Additional jar files are required when you use some features

Source: https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/faq-jdbc.html#01_03_1

[image: The table lists the Oracle JDBC drivers and the JDBC specification supported in that release.]

[image: The Oracle JDBC driver is always compliant to the latest JDK version in each of the new releases. In some versions, JDBC drivers support multiple JDK versions. Use the table below to choose the correct JDBC driver based on your preferred JDK version.]

Comment: My question of ojdbc compatibility goes more toward its comptaibility with Oracle Database version, rather than JDK version.

Comment: I got you. In response to your question, you can see here:

ojdbc8.jar: Certified with JDK9 and JDK8, all the classes to support basic functionality for the Thin driver. Additional jar files are required when you use some features --

and Jean de Lavarene's reply

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the [JDBC FAQ](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/faq-jdbc.html) for more compatibility question. I have pasted here fore details.

[image]